# How to put a UITextField in a UIbutton in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have been trying to change the button title to "Thank you, name". The name part it will come from the user input in a `Textfield`. I Tried converting the `Textfield` to a constant but when I run the app the button title display `<UITextField: 0x...x7f8b29f11060>`. Any help will be appreciated.

```
@IBAction func sayHello(sender : AnyObject){
    let greeting = "Hello, " + textField.text! + "!";
    label.text = greeting;
    textField.resignFirstResponder();

    let name = textField!

    button.setTitle("Thank you \(name)", forState: .Normal)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder();
    return true;
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.delegate = self;
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: button title displays : <UITextfield: 0x...x7f8b29f11060>>

Answer (score 2):

You want name to be textField.text! not textField: `let name = textField!.text`

For better writing and consistence, do this code:

```
let name = textField.text!

let greeting = "Hello, \(name)!";
label.text = greeting;
textField.resignFirstResponder();

button.setTitle("Thank you \(name)!", forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i knew it was something simple but i just couldn't figure out.